# Где лучше всего осуществлять получение локальных данных в Android по Clean Architecture?

Tags: android, архитектура

По сlean, как я понимаю, получение данных должно быть в data слое и вот у меня в проекте выходит, что мне нужно получать данные из файла, но я же не могу передавать контекст через Domain слой в Data слой.

Как стоит осуществлять получение данных из строковых ресурсов или к примеру локального JSON? У меня есть  идея, сделать это через интерфейс, но тогда это все становится бесполезным, как мне кажется.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection (DI).
"передавать контекст" - плохо.
а вот "заинжектить его на низких уровнях" - приемлимо.
еще главное инжектить контекст - application, а не Activity.